# Sqlite given no such column error in polymorphic has many through

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm not sure if it's an error with sqlite, but I had this working in other projects and now I'm getting an error, the scenario is the following.
I hava a categories table, with the following model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
end
```

An Tags table with the following model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :categorizable, polymorphic: true
 belongs_to :category
end
```

And a Question model one of the multiple models that can be categorizable through the polymorphic association:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tags, as: :categoryzable
 has_many :categories, through: :tags
end
```

Using the rails console I can create Tags and get the categorizable object (in this case a Question):

[image]
But when trying to obtain the tags or the categories for a given Question, i'm getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tags.categoryzable_id: SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."categoryzable_id" = ? AND "tags"."categoryzable_type" = ?
```

My db/schema.rb file shows both the categorizable_id and categorizable_type columns for the tags table, so my question is why is sqlite not finding them?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much help I will be since I am currently struggling with the same error, but one thing I noticed was in the Question class you misspelled categorizable.

**Where you have**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tags, as: :categoryzable
 ...
end
```

**Should be**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tags, as: :categorizable
  ...
end
```

Not sure if that will be the final solution, but hopefully a step in the right direction.